# presence of gradient filter changes nav bar layout properties in IE8?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using a tabbed nav bar in a bootstrap.css site. In IE8 (haven't even bothered looking at other IE's yet), the bottom border is off in comparison with how it renders in Chrome. I've narrowed it down to the presence of an IE gradient filter (`filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=0);`) in the style `.navbar-inner` applied from bootstrap's mixins.less file. If I remove that filter from the css, the margins in IE8 match those in Chrome.

The filter has to be removed. Adding `filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);` doesn't seem to help.

My question is: why would that filter change the layout? And what can I do to change that behavior?

Yes, I could just remove the filter, since I'm not using the gradients anyway. But I'm trying to leave bootstrap as untouched as possible, just making changes to it in a separate .less file that gets incorporated into the final bootstrap.css.

Here's a jsfiddle with the essential elements: http://jsfiddle.net/ESEQ2/

To see what I mean, you'll have to look at it in IE8 (possibly other IE's as well).

Grateful for any help here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've seen the same thing in a similar situation - the element in question no longer clears a preceding float after a filter is added.